# Facebook Page - change attributes and settings via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Which **page** attributes can I change by sending a POST to the page? So far I only found the following on the [facebook developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

1. about
2. description
3. general_info
4. website
5. phone

as well as setting a cover photo and setting the page/settings meaning the 4 permissions:
USERS_CAN_POST, USERS_CAN_POST_PHOTOS, USERS_CAN_TAG_PHOTOS, WALL_COMBINED_POSTS

Is there more? What about all the detailed "general information" settings that I can change via facebooks graphical interface like address, personal information, etc. ?